# Prototypical inheritance: how to get instanceof?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

After watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doXpW5AD60Q&index=7&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f) I learned about a nice way to implement inheritance with Javascript: prototypical inheritance. This method uses Object.create/Object.assign to create a new object based on another instance. This seems very interesting given that it is very easy to understand what is going on. For example:

```js
const human = {
  species: 'human',
  create: function(values) {
    const instance = Object.create(this);
    Object.assign(instance, values);
    return instance;
  },
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}`);
  },
  saySpecies: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm a ${this.species}`);
  }
}

const musician = human.create({
  species: 'musician',
  playInstrument: function() {
    console.log(`I'm a musician and I play ${this.instrument}`);
  }
});

const aHuman = human.create({ name: 'Paul' });
aHuman.sayName();
aHuman.saySpecies();

const aMusician = musician.create({ name: 'David', instrument: 'Guitar' });
aMusician.sayName();
aMusician.saySpecies();
aMusician.playInstrument();

// how to check if musician is an instance of human?
console.log(musician instanceof human);
```

With the classical inheritance, I can use `instanceof` to know if a given object has a given **proto** in its chain (e.g. `musician instanceof Human`).

This is what the **proto** chain looks like, which seems very similar to the one created with the `new` operator.

[image]

**Question**
How to achieve the same thing with prototypical inheritance?

Comment: Your code doesn't use `Object.create`.

Comment: sorry let me augment the example to show the Object.create being used.

Comment: done. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It still doesn't use `Object.create`.

Comment: I just replace Object.create with Object.assign which will indeed create a new instance of an object. Let me update the question.

Comment: This code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: can you expand on that @slebetman?

Comment: Both Object.create and Object.assign are static method of the Object object. They are not inherited so there is no such thing as human.create

Comment: `Object.assign` does not create a new object, especially not one based on another object.

Comment: I'm the one providing the human.create. it is just a shortcut for Object.assign({}, this, value);

Comment: `const musician = human.create()` will return an error: "human.create" is not a function

Comment: how so? try to run this: https://repl.it/LvEX/7

Comment: Ah. I missed the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with your attempt:

- The RHS of `instanceof` has to be a function, so your types have to be built on top of functions.
- You are not distinguishing between static/type methods and instance methods. `create` is a type method. `sayName` is an instance method.

The follow should work as you are expecting.

```js
function Human(){}

Object.assign(Human, {
  create: function(values) {
    let newObj = Object.create(this.prototype);
    return Object.assign(newObj, values);
  }
});

Object.assign(Human.prototype, {
  species: 'human',
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}`);
  },
  saySpecies: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm a ${this.species}`);
  }
});

function Musician(){}

Object.assign(Musician, Human);

Musician.prototype = Human.create({
  species: 'musician',
  playInstrument: function() {
    console.log(`I'm a musician and I play ${this.instrument}`);
  }
});

const aHuman = Human.create({ name: 'Paul' });
aHuman.sayName();
aHuman.saySpecies();

const aMusician = Musician.create({ name: 'David', instrument: 'Guitar' });
aMusician.sayName();
aMusician.saySpecies();
aMusician.playInstrument();

// how to check if musician is an instance of human?
console.log(aMusician instanceof Human);
```

Comment: Thanks. this solution works. but if I'm using functions, I guess it is better to use the classical inheritance instead. I've posted another answer where I implement `instanceof` function in the human object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't use inheritance. The only place where a new object is created is in this line:

```
    return Object.assign({}, this, values);
//                       ^^ here
```

`{}` creates a new object that inherits from `Object.prototype`. It's like doing `Object.create(Object.prototype)` or `new Object()`.

Nothing in your code inherits from `human` or `musician`.

Comment: very good point. I've used object assign in the wrong place. I need to use Object.create to keep the __proto__  chain. Let me update my question again.

Comment: I've just updated my question. I added a screenshot for the musician __proto__ object

Answer (score 0):

@JLRishe's answer works. But if you want to avoid using functions and keep using objects you can implement your own version of instanceof. This code snippet also works:

```js
const human = {
  species: 'human',
  create: function(values) {
    let newObj = Object.create(this);
    return Object.assign(newObj, values);
  },
  instanceof: function(obj) {
    if (!Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) {
      return false;
    }
    let isPrototypeOf = (
      this === obj ||
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === obj ||
      this === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) ||
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === obj.prototype
    );
    if (!isPrototypeOf) {
      isPrototypeOf = this.instanceof.call(Object.getPrototypeOf(this), obj);
    }
    return isPrototypeOf;
  },
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}`);
  },
  saySpecies: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm a ${this.species}`);
  }
}

const musician = human.create({
  species: 'musician',
  playInstrument: function() {
    console.log(`I'm a musician and I play ${this.instrument}`);
  }
});

const aHuman = human.create({ name: 'Paul' });
aHuman.sayName();
aHuman.saySpecies();

const aMusician = musician.create({ name: 'David', instrument: 'Guitar' });
aMusician.sayName();
aMusician.saySpecies();
aMusician.playInstrument();

var test = {};

console.log(human.instanceof(human));
console.log(musician.instanceof(human));
console.log(musician.instanceof(Object));
console.log(aHuman.instanceof(human));
console.log(aMusician.instanceof(human));
console.log(aHuman.instanceof(musician));
console.log(aHuman.instanceof(Object));
console.log(aMusician.instanceof(musician));
console.log(musician.instanceof(test));
console.log(human.instanceof(test));
console.log(aMusician.instanceof(test));
console.log(aHuman.instanceof(test));
```